# Adding postmeta default values after adding post

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc, metaweblog

I am using Wordpress XMLRPC to add posts to my blog.

However, after running this.

```
$data = array(
            'title'   => $title,
            'description' => $content,
            'post_type'  => 'post',
            'categories'  => array($category),
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );

            $addedPostReturn = $this->_client->query('metaWeblog.newPost',      
                                    array(0,$username,$password,$data,1));
```

This adds the post fine but doesn't add the postmeta information.

If i open the post, click Update, all the default postmeta gets updated.  However, I would like to add all the default postmeta information with my php script instead of manually (or else it kinda defeats the purpose).

Is there anyway, either with xmlrpc **or regular wordpress functions** to create the postmeta custom fields by using their default values?  If not, is there a way to have the list of all the custom fields i need to manually add using the custom fields section of the metaWeblog.newPost function? (I don't want to add some but not others.  I rather do a complete job)

Thanks in advance... any help is appreciated! :)

EDIT:

```
$postUpdateContent = array();
$postUpdateContent['ID'] = $newPostId;
$postUpdateContent['post_content'] = $sameContent;
wp_update_post( $postUpdateContent );
```

didn't seem to do the trick...